# Lexical Environment and bind()

Tags: javascript, function, closures, this

When creating a function with bind() is a lexical environment also created?
My code works as expected, I am making a Partially applied function with an object and I want to confirm if the reference is never lost when we use currying

```
    let literal = {
    
        nombre: 'Daniel'
    };
    function parcial(unObjeto, numero) {
    
        console.log(unObjeto);
    }
    let vinculada = parcial.bind(null, literal);
    vinculada(); // {nombre: 'Daniel'}
    
    literal.nuevapropiedad = 'nuevo valor';
    vinculada(); // {nombre: 'Daniel', nuevapropiedad: 'nuevo valor'}
```

**I see that if I modify the "literal" object later in the code the linked function reads that "updated" object**.

To the best of my knowledge this has logic because bind() creates a lexical environment that closes in this case on "literal" as if it did with the first argument (in this case I don't want to use the first argument) and it will never lose the reference.

**Basically I want to keep the reference to "literal" in my function so I don't have to worry about passing it back every time I change "literal"**.

Comment: if you do `let vinculada = parcial.bind(null, {...literal});` - though, that will only be a shallow copy

Comment: so how am I doing it is okay if I want to keep the reference, right?

Comment: oh, yeah - didn't know which way you wanted that to go

Comment: Basically I want to keep the reference to "literal" in my function so I don't have to worry about passing it back every time I change "literal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lexical environment is about **scope**. And words used to describe scope include things like `close-over` and `global` etc.

However, `.bind()` does not work with scope. Instead it works with **bindings**. Binding is a concept orthogonal to scope. Where scope defines what variables are accessible in what part of code, binding defines on what objects do methods operate on.

They are not the same concept (though languages like Java confuse the issue because it does not actually have a real concept of multiple **scopes** but instead calls binding "scope").

This is **scope**:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

function foo (c) {
    var d = 3;
    var b = 4;

    a = 5;

    console.log(a, b, c, d);
}

foo(10); // logs 5, 4, 10, 3

console.log(a, b); // logs 5, 2
console.log(c, d); // throws error because c and d don't exist
```

This is **binding**:

```
var x = {}

x.hello = 1;

x.sayHello = function () {
    console.log(this.hello);
}

x.sayHello(); // logs 1
```

Function arguments, global variables, variables inside functions etc. are handled by the **scope** mechanism which in the case of javascript creates closures. They don't have anything to do with binding.

The value of `this` is handled by the **binding** mechanism (inheritance, `.bind()` etc.) and don't have anything to do with scope.

Basically `.bind()` does not affect the lexical environment and the lexical environment does not affect bindings (though you could argue that arrow functions are a kind of lexical binding).

Comment: Ok, so in my example it keeps the reference to "literal" because of the bindings instead of a "scope".

Comment: Yes. Bindings are more about objects and scopes are more about functions

Comment: Great, so with this bind() binding to "literal" it is no longer necessary to pass the object every time "literal" changes? i.e. will "vinculada" always work with updated "literal"?